# Is there a relation between the so-called volatility drag and the sigma term in Black-Scholes' model?

Tags: volatility, black-scholes-pde, geometric-brownian

The closed-form solution of Black Scholes Dynamics
$dS_t=S_t(\mu dt +\sigma dW_t$) is
$$S_t=S_0 e^{(\mu -\sigma ^2/2) t+\sigma dW_t}.$$

The $-\sigma^2/2$ term is quite similar to the volatility drag when transforming an arithmetic return to a geometric return. Are there any relationship between the two?